# Why a method returning arraylis returns same values?

Tags: java, hibernate, list, arraylist

I am using Hibernate , I wrote a method which returns array list, the query is supposed to return 11 objects(rows) but here it returns 11 same objects(I mean 11 rows are same).
Here is my code.

```
ArrayList<HistoryLatitudeBean> vehicleHistoryDetails = new ArrayList<HistoryLatitudeBean>();

vehicleHistoryDetails=FetchVehicleHistDetails.getVehicleHistory(selectedVehicle,frmDate,toDate);
```

The getVehicleHistory() method is as follows,

```
public static ArrayList<HistoryLatitudeBean> getVehicleHistory(String selectedVehicle, Date frmDate, Date toDate) {
    Session session = HibernateSession.getHibernateSession();

    // Starting Transaction
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    String hql = null;
    ArrayList<HistoryLatitudeBean> vehicleHistoryList = new ArrayList<HistoryLatitudeBean>();
    try {

         hql="FROM HistoryLatitudeBean where vehicleno=:vehicleno and rdate BETWEEN :fromdate and :todate ";
         Query query =session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("vehicleno", 12);
        query.setParameter("fromdate", frmDate);
        query.setParameter("todate", toDate);
        List<HistoryLatitudeBean> groupList = (List<HistoryLatitudeBean>)query.list();

       //--->Here I checked through debug point , all object are same.

        for(HistoryLatitudeBean arr : groupList){
            vehicleHistoryList.add(arr);     


        }
        transaction.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (transaction!=null) transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{

        session.close();
    }

    return vehicleHistoryList;
}
```

Whats going wrong can anyone tell me . It really helpful to me. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you tell us what's going wrong? I don't know it...

Comment: Because you're just querying the record with `vehicleno` 12 everytime.

Comment: @J.Lucky No I have 11 rows for different dates for vehicle no 12. Here  If I execute 1 query it returns 11 object I am trying to put it in arraylist. But arraylist object shows all objects are same.

Comment: @ZerO I am getting same 11 objects by executing the query but it suposed to return 11 different object because I have 11 diff rows for diff dates.

Comment: You mean your `groupList`contains different objects?

Comment: @J.Lucky no it suppose to be diff object but in my case all are same.

Comment: are you sure these are the same objects? can you run this query on the database server and check the result?

Comment: @zerocool yes I have checked . . all are same .

Comment: hmm... did you execute this query in DB server, with the same vechileNo, startDate and endDate? how many records are getting fetched with above parameter values?

Comment: @zerocool 11 records.

Comment: How did you determine that they are the same objects?

Comment: When you run it on your databsae server, and it returned the same records, then the problem is in your sql query. Fix it.

Comment: @J.Lucky I tried a lot., cant you identify any mistakes?